# Call method of static class with string name

Tags: php, laravel

In routers/web.php :

```
Route::get('/{page}/{id}/{seo_title}', "Router@get");
```

In Router class which is a controller :

```
public function get($page,$id,$seo_title)
    {
        $view_arg = null;
        if($id)
        {
           $model =  "tbl_$page"."s";

            $view_arg =  $model::whereId($id)->first();  
            //  Error: Class 'tbl_posts' not found 

            //$view_arg =  call_user_func(array($model, 'whereId'),$id)->first(); 
            // Error : call_user_func() expects parameter 1 to be a valid callback, class 'tbl_posts' not found 
        }
      // Some other codes...
}
```

I got the error:

> Error: Class 'tbl_posts' not found

On the follwing line:

```
$view_arg =  $model::whereId($id)->first();
```

While the follwing code works fine :

```
tbl_posts::whereId($id)->first();
```

I've also tried the following :

```
$view_arg =  call_user_func(array($model, 'whereId'),$id)->first();
```

And it gives me the error

> Error : call_user_func() expects parameter 1 to be a valid
>   callback, class

Comment: Is `tbl_posts` in a namespace?

Comment: No, It's a class (model)

Comment: Pass complete path of model call in string variable. `$model = App\Posts` then `$view_arg =  $model::whereId($id)->first();`

Comment: To check, can you show what `echo tbl_posts::class;` gives.

Comment: You will have to `use` the Model class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can directly call your Model Class in function.

```
public function get($page,$id,$seo_title)
{
    $view_arg = null;
    if($id)
    {
       $model =  "App\\" . "tbl_$page"."s"; 

        $view_arg =  $model::whereId($id)->first();  

    }
}
```

Comment: tbl_posts is my model name, not Post. And I have added {use App\tbl_posts;}

Comment: As I mentioned earlier it workes fine when I'm working with class directly.
{tbl_posts::whereId($id)->first();}  works fine.

Comment: Sorry the first method is not working. User the second method in my answer.

Comment: @Deepak the first method works.  But it doesn't have dynamic `use`. I like the second way, but you need to add a double backslash when using double-quotes.

Comment: Thank You, It worked. But what you said before the "Or" is nonsense because as I said my model name is tbl_posts, not Post.

Comment: will make changes in the answer so other can use it. Thanks.